# Why is a "finally" block required in this code

Tags: java, try-catch-finally

I am aware that it is valid to create a try-catch segment without a
finally block. So in hacking around with this code, I can't figure out
what java logic (e.g. rule, theory) forces me to include a finally block
in this segment of code - and why the finally block has to include a return
statement in it. In other words, if I remove the finally
block completely I receive an error, and if I replace the return statement
in the finally block with anything else (e.g. System.out.printl(''foo")), I
still receive an error insisting that I include a return statement. Again,
the code as written here compiles and runs fine. I'm just trying to understand
a little bit of the theory behind the try-catch-finally construct (p.s. I understand
that its all about "exception handling"... but my question is really more about
code flow and the return statement).

```
class foo {
    int getInt() {
        try {
            String[] students = {"student1", "student2"};
            System.out.println(students[4]);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            return 10;
        }
        finally {
            return 20;
        }
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        foo classSize = new foo();
        System.out.println(classSize.getInt());
    }
}
```

Comment: The trick is to **read** the error message. Without finally block, if there is no exception, what does the method return?

Comment: The `return 20` could just as well fall outside the try/catch, at the end of the method, or at the end of the `try` block.  There's nothing wrong with how it's done above, though.

Comment: Having a `finally` block fixes a compile, but logically it is a mistake.

Comment: (My preference would be at the end of the method.  Or place a comment there indicating where the `return` is assumed to occur.)

Comment: Someone is giving you a trick question. Does the `20` in the finally block, which will be executed *after* the catch block, replace the `10`? [Hint: yes] `return` in finally blocks is legal but *a bad idea.*

Comment: If I include a valid value (e.g. 0) as an Array length, but remove the finally block I receive the same error ["missing return statement"].

Comment: @AndrewLazarus - Excellent point!!

Comment: @HotLicks: most of the time, it must be inside the try block, because it needs to return something that is only available in the scope of the try block.

Comment: The rule is that, for a value-returning method, there must be a `return <some_value>;` statement along EVERY path to a non-exception exit from the method.  If you remove the `return` in the `finally` clause and don't replace it with one elsewhere, then the method can exit without specifying a return value.

Comment: Andrew. You're correct. It is a trick question, and I do understand that the return in the finally block will override the return statement in the catch block. I also understand that logically the way that this code is written is "not too bright". I get it. I'm just trying to understand "why" I'm FORCED to include a finally block with a return value at all...?

Comment: Thanks Hot Licks. That gets me lots closer!

Comment: @dasblinklight Thanks. Makes much sense too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider the execution paths without the `finally`

```
int getInt() {
    try {
        String[] students = {"student1", "student2"};
        System.out.println(students[4]);
        // no return
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        return 10; // if an exception occurs 
    }
    // no return
}
```

So what happens if no exception is thrown? You won't have a return value.

You can either provide a `finally` and put a return there or you can put a return outside the `try-catch` block.

Note that the `finally` in your `try-catch-finally` block has a `return` statement that will supersede the `catch`'s `return` statement since a `finally` block is always executed if its associated `try[-catch]` is executed. You may want to go with the following

```
int getInt() {
    try {
        String[] students = {"student1", "student2"};
        System.out.println(students[4]);
        // the return could be here as well
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        return 10; // in case of failure
    }
    return 20; // in case of success
}
```

All execution paths **must** end up returning a value (or throwing an exception).

Comment: or put a return at the end of the try block (the most natural place to me)

Comment: So if an error occurs, then the final block does not execute because the catch block already returns a value. Is this correct?

Comment: @bbalchev: no. A finally block always executes. That's the whole point of a finally block.

Comment: Alright, thanks. It's always good to learn from tricky questions as well.

Comment: This was suggested by another commenter. Writing the code like this will not compile. I receive the same error. [e.g. "error: missing return statement"]

Comment: Actually, Eclipse gives a warning for the redundant `finally`. It suggests:
@SuppressWarnings("finally")

Comment: @vee Are you referring to the first code snippet? Note how it says "Consider the execution paths _without_ the `finally`". It's not meant to compile. It demonstrates why it fails if there is no `finally` (or other `return` statement).

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Makes sense. I'll have to play with it a bit to own it. But I see the logic now. Thanks